# Slow text rendering with many text boxes

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, performance

I am a Windows Forms developer and I am currently toying around with WPF. To do a quick performance comparison of the two technologies regarding text rendering in text boxes, I wrote a little program that creates a huge number of text boxes in a window and updates their text every 100ms.

To my surprise, the WPF version of the test application renders much slower than the WinForms version. Most of the time the application does not respond at all, for example when I try to resize the window. The WinForms version of the application runs smoothly.

So my question is: Is there something wrong with the way I use the WPF controls (I use a WrapPanel as controls container in WPF and a FlowLayoutPanel in the WinForms)? Or is text rendering really slower than in WinForms?

WPF:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PerformanceTestWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Random _r = new Random();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox {Height = 23, Width = 120, Text = "TextBox"});

            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0, 100);
            _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
            _timer.Start();

        }

        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var child in wrapPanel.Children)
            {
                var textBox = child as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.Text = _r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WinForms:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PerformanceTestWinforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer _timer = new Timer();
        Random _r = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Height = 23, Width = 120, Text = "TextBox" });

            _timer.Interval = 100;
            _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var child in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                var textBox = child as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.Text = _r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't jump to conclusions here. Maybe it's the dispatcher cycles that are expensive. Can't do profiling on my machine (requires higher credentials); see if you can do that to find out which functions actually are the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the explicit dispatching, try this binding based example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfPerfTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer _timer;
        Random _r = new Random();

        private readonly List<ValueViewModel<string>> _values = new List<ValueViewModel<string>>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                var value = new ValueViewModel<string>();
                var tb = new TextBox { Height = 23, Width = 120 };
                tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = value });
                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(tb);
                this._values.Add(value);
            }

            _timer = new Timer(o =>
            {
                foreach (var value in this._values)
                    value.Value = _r.Next(0, 1000).ToString();
            }, null, 0, 100);
        }
    }

    class ValueViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
    {

        private T _Value = default(T);
        public T Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _Value)
                {
                    _Value = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

During resizing it's still choking quite a bit, but other than that it performs much better.

Comment: Thanks, this really works much better. But why is dispatching faster here (I guess some kind of implicit dispatching is happening here, since the timer is now a System.Threading.Timer which executes the callback asynchronously)?

Comment: If you use bindings the dispatching happens implicitly and is thus presumably scheduled more efficiently or the update is merged into the existing loops. The WPF dispatcher internals are fairly complex, would recommend [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.